# QTP doesnt recognize same VB windows object in next build

Tags: qtp

We are working on a project which uses VB script & QTP to automate a VB application. On 1st build QTP was able to recognize a window object in the VB application. But in the next build QTP didnt recognize the same window object & suggested that the window object is of different ID. how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more details - it's hard to tell you how to fix you problem without more context. For example, what does the GUI Spy show for the object for build 1? What does the spy show for the same object in build 2? If the id is not consistent, you may need to use a regular expression to match a pattern, or use one or more different properties to identify the object.

Comment: there is no pattern, we will try to see properties to identify the object